# Nunjucks iterate over items in an array to display items in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, static-site, nunjucks

In javascript I can loop over an array to output my object as shown below.

```
var myArr = ["one","two","three"]
var myObj = {
  "one": {
    "title": "ones",
    "desc": "this is one"
  },
  "three": {
    "title": "threes",
    "desc": "this is three"
  },
  "two": {
    "title": "twos",
    "desc": "this is two"
  }
}

myArr.forEach(function (value) {
  console.log(myObj[value].title, myObj[value].desc);
});
```

outputs

`ones this is one`

`twos this is two`

`threes this is three`

```
console.log("number 2 - ",myObj[myArr[1]].desc)
console.log("number 2 - ",myObj["two"].desc)
```

outputs

`number 2 -  this is two`

`number 2 -  this is two`

I want to be able to do this in nunjucks as I want to control the order of display from `myArr` but also want the flexibility to be able to have a single page eg one.html where I can target one specifically eg `{{testObj.one.title}}`.

How can this be acheived with nunjucks? I have tried the below.

```
-- nunjucks --
<ul>
  {% for item in testArr %}
    <li>{{item}} - {{testObj.one.title}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<ul>
   {% for obj, item in testObj %}
      <li>{{ obj }}: {{ item | dump }} - {{ item.title }} - {{ item.desc }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>

--- output ---
<ul>
  <li>one - ones</li>
  <li>two - ones</li>
  <li>three - ones</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>one: {"title":"ones","desc":"this is one"} - ones - this is one</li>
  <li>three: {"title":"threes","desc":"this is three"} - threes - this is three</li>
  <li>two: {"title":"twos","desc":"this is two"} - twos - this is two</li>
</ul>
```

My ideal output to get to would be like the below where I can order my display based on `myArr` but for each item show the contents of their key in `myObj`

```
<ul>
  <li>one - ones</li>
  <li>two - twos</li>
  <li>three - threes</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<ul>
  {% for item in myArr %}
    <li>{{item}} - {{myObj[item].title}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

?